# Checking that XML output works

Tags: php, xml, google-maps-api-3

I have been stuck with this error since a week now, i have googled and tried every possible solution including the ones on Stackoverflow. This is my code:

```
<?php
require("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php");
// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect ("localhost", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Not connected : " . mysqli_error());
}
// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, name, address, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( 
  radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - 
  radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS 
  distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 
  20",
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $center_lng),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $radius));
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
    die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute("id", $row['id']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

My goal is to output the XML to the browser to make sure that it's working but i have been getting these errors:

[image]
For more info see:https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator
Can someone help me out???

Comment: You should indent your code properly. It helps everyone read your code and it is good for you as well.

Comment: Can you paste your XML output? That's a browser message, not a PHP error_log message

Comment: @delboy1978uk my XML output is the image attached

Comment: @ryantxr indentation done.

Comment: Please verify what you are getting in $_GET.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the PHP is outputting something (6 characters, probably white space) before it executes `header("Content-type: text/xml");`.  Might even be in `phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php`.

Comment: The issue might be in this file `phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php`

Comment: This is what i have got in **phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php** :
`<?php
$username="root";
$password="2015";
$database="guide";
?>`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough to go on to actually solve your problem. You can use the following to ensure that you are getting the input you expect.

```
$required = ['lat', 'lng'];
$missing = array_diff($required, $_GET);
if ( ! empty($missing) ) {
    $missingString = implode(',', $missing);
    die("missing {$missingString}");
}
```

With XML, the opening

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

cannot have a space before it. Your PHP code somewhere is outputting spaces before the echo outputs the XML.

Comment: I put this at the head of my code, this is the output i am getting on the browser:    
**missing** **lat**,**lng**    
If i remove it then i get:  
**Notice: Undefined index: lat in C:\xampp\htdocs\storelocator.php on line 5**

Comment: $_GET does not contain what you think it contains. Check how you are accessing the page.

Comment: ! I have tried all i could but still no solution! If you could help me out please! This is the tutorial i am following: https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator

Answer (score -1):

That's a browser message, not a PHP error_log message.

Something has output before the XML. Most likely a PHP warning or notice. Suppress that rubbish!

For the best error logging experience, set `error_reporting` to -1, turn `display_errors` off, and set a custom `error_log`. Then in the terminal, type `tail -f /path/to/error_log`. Your notices, warnings and errors will now scroll past in real time, without distorting your web page's display.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! But i am not using a cdl interface, i am rather using phpmyadmin from xampp and sublime as an editor!

Comment: I did what you said, but now i am getting another error:
Undefined index: lat in C:\xampp\htdocs\storelocator.php on line 4
Undefined index: lng in C:\xampp\htdocs\storelocator.php on line 5
Undefined index: radius in C:\xampp\htdocs\storelocator.php on line 6

Comment: That means $_GET["lat"] isn't set. Are you sure you didn't mean $_POST? A GET var is in the url like http://blah.com/my/url?getvar=value